# Is this a legitimate alternative to the "traditional" dispose pattern for class hierarchies?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, finalizer, boilerplate

I am not a fan of boilerplate code: copy-paste reuse is potentially error-prone. Even if you use code snippets or smart templates, there is no guarantee the other developer did, which means there's no guarantee they did it right. And, if you have to see the code, you have to understand it and/or maintain it.

What I want to know from the community is: is my implementation of **IDispose** for a class hierarchy a legitimate alternative to the ["traditional" dispose pattern](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae)? By legitimate, I mean correct, reasonably well performing, robust, and maintainable.

*I am ok with this alternative being plain wrong, but if it is, I'd like to know why.*

This implementation assumes you have full control over the class hierarchy; if you don't you'll probably have to resort back to boilerplate code. The calls to **Add*()** would typically be made in the constructor.

```
public abstract class DisposableObject : IDisposable
{
  protected DisposableObject()
  {}

  protected DisposableObject(Action managedDisposer)
  {
     AddDisposers(managedDisposer, null);
  }

  protected DisposableObject(Action managedDisposer, Action unmanagedDisposer)
  {
     AddDisposers(managedDisposer, unmanagedDisposer);
  }

  public bool IsDisposed
  {
     get { return disposeIndex == -1; }
  }

  public void CheckDisposed()
  {
     if (IsDisposed)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("This instance is disposed.");
  }

  protected void AddDisposers(Action managedDisposer, Action unmanagedDisposer)
  {
     managedDisposers.Add(managedDisposer);
     unmanagedDisposers.Add(unmanagedDisposer);
     disposeIndex++;
  }

  protected void AddManagedDisposer(Action managedDisposer)
  {
     AddDisposers(managedDisposer, null);
  }

  protected void AddUnmanagedDisposer(Action unmanagedDisposer)
  {
     AddDisposers(null, unmanagedDisposer);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
     if (disposeIndex != -1)
     {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
     }
  }

  ~DisposableObject()
  {
     if (disposeIndex != -1)
        Dispose(false);
  }

  private void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
     for (; disposeIndex != -1; --disposeIndex)
     {
        if (disposing)
           if (managedDisposers[disposeIndex] != null)
              managedDisposers[disposeIndex]();
        if (unmanagedDisposers[disposeIndex] != null)
           unmanagedDisposers[disposeIndex]();
     }
  }

  private readonly IList<Action> managedDisposers = new List<Action>();
  private readonly IList<Action> unmanagedDisposers = new List<Action>();
  private int disposeIndex = -1;
}
```

This is a "complete" implementation in the sense I provide support for finalization (knowing most implementations don't need a finalizer), checking whether an object is disposed, etc. A real implementation may remove the finalizer, for example, or create a subclass of **DisposableObject** that includes the finalizer. Basically, I threw in everything I could think of just for this question.

There are probably some edge cases and esoteric situations I've missed, so I invite anyone to poke holes in this approach or to shore it up with corrections.

Other alternatives might be to use a single **Queue<Disposer> disposers** in **DisposableObject** instead of two lists; in this case, as disposers are called, they are removed from the list. There are other slight variations I can think of, but they have the same general result: no boilerplate code.

Comment: This still suffers from the fact that implementors have to remember to call the Add() method for aggregated types. Personally, I don't think this has any benefit over the usual pattern.

Comment: Don't do it. Use the Dispose Pattern as written. Experienced developers will understand the code at a glance, you'll cover all the bases, tools such as FxCop can help validate it, you can write snippets to implement it accurately, and you'll be adhering to the Microsoft standards.

http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae

Comment: As an aside, if what you want is a DisposableCollection<TDisposable>, you should be able to find a number of implementations of that.

Comment: Ok, I just realized there's at least one problem. If an unmanagedDisposer throws, none of the "base" disposers are run. This doesn't happen in the traditional pattern because the base finalizers will always be run.

Comment: Almost exact dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874764/is-this-idisposable-implementation-correct/874782#874782

Comment: @spender: Not a dupe at all, since this implementation works by keeping a LIST of objects to dispose; for set-once fields, I think such an approach has a lot to offer, since it allows the same code to create the IDisposable objects and ensure their cleanup.  In vb.net, if constructors are protected and are only publicly available via factory methods, one can go further, and take care of declaration, initialization, and cleanup, all in the same line of code, a pattern which is much nicer IMHO than having declaration in one place, initialization in another, and cleanup in a third.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue you will potentially hit is that C# only allows you to inherit from a single base class, which in this case will **always** be `DisposableObject`. Right here you have cluttered your class hierarchy by forcing additional layers so that classes that need to inherit from `DisposableObject` and some other object can do so.

You are also introducing a lot of overhead and maintenance issues down the road with this implementation (not to mention the repeated training costs everytime someone new comes on to the project and you have to explain how they should use this implementation rather than the defined pattern). You know have multiple states to keep track of with your two lists, there is no error handling around the calls to the actions, the syntax when calling an action looks "wierd" (while it may be common to invoke a method from an array, the syntax of simply putting the () after the array access just looks strange).

I understand the desire to reduce the amount of boilerplate you have to write, but disposability is generally not one of those areas that I would recommend taking short-cuts or otherwise deviating from the pattern. The closest I usually get is to use a helper method (or an extension method) that wraps the actual call to `Dispose()` on a given object. These calls typically look like:

```
if (someObject != null)
{
   someObject.Dispose();
}
```

This can be simplified using a helper method, but keep in mind that FxCop (or any other static analysis tool that checks for correct dispose implementations) will complain.

As far as performance is concerned, keep in mind that you are making a lot of delegate calls with this type of implementation. This is, by nature of a delegate, somewhat more costly than a normal method call.

Maintainability is definately an issue here. As I mentioned, you have the repeated training costs everytime someone new comes on to the project and you have to explain how they should use this implementation rather than the defined pattern. Not only that, you have problems with everyone remembering to add their disposable objects to your lists.

Overall, I think doing this is a bad idea that will cause a lot of problems down the road, especially as the project and team size increase.

Comment: Good points, especially on the training issue. As I said I'm ok with it being wrong. I'm interested to hear what else comes up.

Answer (score 2):

I occasionally have need for tracking several open files at a time or other resources.  When I do I use a utility class similar to the following.  Then the object still implements the Displose() as you suggest, even tracking multiple lists (managed/unmanaged) is easy and obvious to developers whats going on.  Additionally the derivation from the List object is no accident, it allows you call Remove(obj) if needed.  My constructor usually looks like:

```
        _resources = new DisposableList<IDisposable>();
        _file = _resources.BeginUsing(File.Open(...));
```

And here is the class:

```
    class DisposableList<T> : List<T>, IDisposable
        where T : IDisposable
    {
        public bool IsDisposed = false;
        public T BeginUsing(T item) { base.Add(item); return item; }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            for (int ix = this.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
            {
                try { this[ix].Dispose(); }
                catch (Exception e) { Logger.LogError(e); }
                this.RemoveAt(ix);
            }
            IsDisposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the general pattern from csharptest's answer.  Having a base class designed around disposal is a bit limiting, but if you're using vb.net or don't mind some games with thread-static variables, a specially-designed base class will make it possible to register variables for disposal even when they're created in field initializers or derived-class constructors (normally, if an exception is thrown in a field initializer, there's no way to dispose any already-allocated IDisposable fields, and if the constructor of a derived class throws an exception there's no way for the partially-created base object to dispose itself).

I wouldn't bother with your unmanaged resources list, though.  Classes with finalizers shouldn't hold references to any objects not required for finalization.  Instead, the stuff needed for finalization should be placed in its own class, and the "main" class should create an instance of that latter class and keep a reference to it.